# C# server array to client / javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

This has probably been asked before but I can't seem to find any answers that I can get to work.

I have a SQL query that produces five rows of data in the backend.
And I then fetch the data from the query like so:

```
   if (reader.HasRows) {
    var list = new List < GetUserNames > ();
    // Read advances to the next row.
    while (reader.Read()) {
     //Person p = new Person();
     // To avoid unexpected bugs access columns by name.

     //Convert.ToInt32(dataReader.GetValue(3));
     wholeAvg = Decimal.Round(reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("wholeavg")), 2);

     list.Add(new GetUserNames {
      users = reader.GetString(2)
     });
     allRecords = list.ToArray();

    }

   }
```

Now what I would like to send to the client and use with javascript is the allRecords array.
Can someone point me in the right direction how to get the array from the backend?

Thanks!

Comment: What type of application is it?  (webforms, MVC, WebAPI etc..)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Comment: Application is webform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could serialize it to JSON then store the value in a hidden input. In your javascript you can then pick up the value of that field:

.cs:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allRecords);
hdUsers.Value = json;
```

.aspx:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdUsers"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

var jsonString = $("[id$='hdUsers']").val()

var arr = JSON.parse(jsonString);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try

Comment: Hi, this seems to be working, now I have the values in array like {"users": "value1", "users": "value2"} Now I just need to get those values out of the array..  any clues?

Comment: the array looks like this: [{"users":"value1"},{"users":"value2"},{"users":"value3"},{"users":"value4"},{"users":"value5"}]

Comment: You can access the array values by index e.g. arr[0], arr[1], etc. When you have the objects you can then access the properties by name e.g. arr[1].Name

Comment: Thanks that was easier than I thought. Appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC, you can add 'allrecords' to TempData and use following code;

```
var records = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["Records"]))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I wish I was using MVC.. and I will in the future projects. Now I'm using plain old way to get values in .cs file and print it out in the .aspx file.

Comment: [Pass Values from CodeBehind to JavaScript](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/347_Pass_Values_from_CodeBehind_to_JavaScript_and_From_JavaScript_to_CodeBehind_in_ASPNet.aspx) Maybe this link can help you